# The results of the different Web pages written in google web toolkit and html

Tags: html, gwt, web

We are developing a web using google web toolkit (hereinafter gwt).
I write code to show the same results as expected and creates an html, gwt
I get different results.
Chrome, Firefox, Opera, ie11 the good but, ie8 ~ 10 only comes differently.
Do you know why minutes are appreciated, such as the results come out I need to know.

You can determine the source and the results screen at the following link.
http://blog.naver.com/dfhrtjyk/220264601882

Comment: Please add the source and the results screen to your question it self

Comment: I don't have permission to upload result image. So uploaded source and images on another web page. And I link the web page.

Comment: Are you sure your test.html is in "standards mode" and not "quirks mode"? Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top.

Comment: Thomas Broyer - Thank you. How do I get gwt result as like not adding the <!DOCTYPE html> in test.html?